# Create comma separated string via xml values

Tags: php, xml, split, nodes

I'm working on some system for a few hours now and this little thing is too much for me to think logically about at the moment.
Normally I would wait a few hours but this is a last minute job and I need to finish this.

Here's my problem:

I have an XML file that gets posted to my PHP file, the PHP file inserts certain data into a DB, but some XML nodes have the same name:

```
<accessoires>
<accessoire>value1</accessoire>
<accessoire>value2</accessoire>
<accessoire>value3</accessoire>
</accessoires>
```

Now I want to get a var $acclist which contains all  values seperated by a comma:
value1,value2,value3,

I bet the solution to this is very easy but I'm at the known point where even the easiest piece of code becomes a hassle. And googling only comes up with nodes that in some way have their own identifiers.

Could someone help me out please?

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I know its some for each loop probably but I dont know how to handle it any further..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simplexml_load_string to parse the html then call implode on the node after casting to an array.

**NOTE** This code was tested in php 5.4.6 and behaves as expected.

```
<?php
$xml = '<accessoires>
<accessoire>value1</accessoire>
<accessoire>value2</accessoire>
<accessoire>value3</accessoire>
</accessoires>';
$dat = simplexml_load_string($xml);
echo implode(",",(array)$dat->accessoire);
```

For 5.3.x I had to change to

```
$xml = '<accessoires>
<accessoire>value1</accessoire>
<accessoire>value2</accessoire>
<accessoire>value3</accessoire>
</accessoires>';
$dat = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$dat = (array)$dat;
echo implode(",",$dat["accessoire"]);
```

Comment: echo implode(",",(array)$dat->accessoire);
Doesnt contain any data.
    echo implode(",",(array)$dat->accessoires->accessoire); 
only shows me one value of one <accessoire>

Answer (score -1):

You do this by taking a library that is able to parse and process XML, for example with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/SimpleXML):

```
implode(',', iterator_to_array($accessoires->accessoire, FALSE));
```

The key part here is to use [`iterator_to_array()`](http://php.net/iterator_to_array) as SimpleXML offers the same-named child-elements here as an iterator. Otherwise `$accessoires->accessoire` gives you auto-magically only the first element (if any).